# Thread synchronization with mixed C and C++

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have a multithreaded program with the main thread being third-party (can't change it) and pure C. My task is to build new modules (in C++) around it, those reside partly in other threads and need to use the C program's interface. Basically just reading some variables (ints, floats, nothing complicated) that are stored and updated in the C thread.

Now to my question: How can I make sure that I don't get rubbish out of the C interface when accessing those variables as I can't use a mutex to lock it while reading. Is this even possible? Or is writing a float/int an atomic operation anyway?

Comment: Mixing C/C++ has little to do with the problem. I'd suggest calling this thread "data synchronization with external library" or something like that.

Comment: What CPU and operating system? I think this will have impact on what is going to be atomic and what not. Additionally, you'll always have problems with caching, that is other thread has changed the value but it has not been written to main RAM yet, so you'd better not be doing anything where having a slightly outdated value is a fatal problem.

Comment: That's what I was thinking... and I don't want to make it dependent on some special architecture.

Comment: @fewu - can you give some more detail about the structure of the "main thread" and C portion of the problem, and how the C++ program will interact with it? You mention the main thread will be C, and you cannot change it, but this raises the question - how do the C++ threads get kicked off in the first place? Also (and this should really be the first question) - what does the C code itself document wrt thread safety? Granted, the answer is probably "nothing", but it was at least worth a shot.

Comment: The main thread is C (actually generated code out of Matlab Simulink) with a defined interface that I implemented in C++ because I have to interface another C++ library (which is also 3rd party). In this C++ implementation I kick off the C++ threads.
Concerning your second question: There is nothing about thread safety, just as you suspected.

Comment: So the threads that you kick off call back into the C API, and the main C thread may be concurrently modifying those values? One option might be to tunnel all your requests to the main thread, e.g., put your requests on a queue, and when the main thread calls back out into your C++ code, you take the chance to drain the thread, make the API calls, send the results back to the waiting threads.

Comment: I got in touch with the third party and they agreed to create to create a new call from their C code that takes the value I'm interested in as parameter so that they call my C++ code instead of me calling the C interface. Like this, I can implement the function call as C++ and use mutexes to control the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Reading and writing anything is not an atomic operation and if you cannot change the C code, you are out of luck. Syncronization always needs *both* parts to be syncronized.

Your best bet is to ask the third party to make their part thread safe and/or share a locking mechanism with you.

Comment: You can generally do all the locking in your own calling code - protecting every call into the unknown code so only one thread is ever in the C library at one time.  Since this effectively renders access to the C library single threaded, it's pretty much guaranteed to work.  This technique has been used to interact with crufty native libraries since, well, since there were crufty native libraries.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll do. Ask the 3rd party to create an interface like `WriteNewValue(int newVal)` that they call every time they update the value so that I can duplicate the variable into my C++ world where I can lock/unlock access.

Answer (score 5):

Statements like "writing a float/int [is] an atomic operation anyway" are, unfortunately, not well defined in C or C++ (although with the use of `std::atomic` in C++11 and the stdatomic.h methods from C11 can help here - but that's not going to help you with C interop for a library you can't modify, so you can probably ignore it here).

You can find guidance about these issues on specific compilers and platforms - for example, you can probably figure out that on most platforms, aligned 32-bit or 64-bit reads or writes will be atomic, if aligned, and that most compilers will align them appropriately.

However, down this road lies madness. If you have multiple threads involve, just use POSIX/pthreads functionality, like [pthreads mutexes](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexLocking) - which are easily accessible from both C and C++, to guard any access to state shared across threads.

Since you can't modify the C code, you may have to do all the locking in the C++ code, before any call to the C library, unlocking after. If you can read, but not modify the C code, or the document is very clear about the threading/sharing model, you may be able to use a fine grained locking strategy, but in the absence of any profiling indicating a bottleneck, I'd start with one global lock you use to guard every access to the C API.

Comment: If writes are unsynchronized, locking on reads only is pointless.

Comment: c11 has atomic just as well. stdatomic.h

Comment: I never suggested locking on reads only. I'm suggesting locking on any call into the C library, which would encompass all reads and writes (by the native library). If there is any actual shared state (e.g., global variables exposed by the shared library) you'll need to do locking on the C++ side when you access it.

Comment: Thanks self, I learned something new. It's been a while since I wrote C :) - answer updated.

Comment: @self - which raises another point - C++ has std::atomic, and C11 has stdatomic.h, and use of those methods is well-defined "within the family" so to speak (i.e., within the C++ and C worlds), but is there any way to get interop on shared state in a well-defined way between C++ and C using them? I'm guessing not since (a) they operate on different data types (even if the underlying type is likely to be identical and coercible) and (b) implementation decisions mean that, in theory, different techniques were chosen to make reads and writes visible to each other, so that mixing is not allowed.

Comment: @Dariusz - after reading the OP's problem description more carefully, it seems you have a point - he is implying that the "main thread" is owned by, and will stay completely within, the C code, which would complicate matters. This seems unlikely by design - how did the C++ threads get kicked off them, and is an inversion of the usual model where you embed a C library, but I'll asked the OP for clarification.

Comment: @BeeOnRope We had that. Since the original C code is not multithreaded  it will call into the new module and expect the answer as a return value from the call. You then need to interface with the original C API further down the callstack. While you are in the call you can simply use classical locking as described. But once you are out, you basically have to wait for the next call into your module. But the nature of things, you probably don't need to if you design your module properly and don't break the originals program design assumptions.

Comment: I didn't understand who the "we" is this case. Are you related to the OP? If the driving code is a single thread of C code, which calls into C++ code (which might in turn call back into the C code) - how do multiple threads get introduced? Assuming they aren't, there should be no problem writing your C++ callbacks as usual.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The only right way to work in this scenario is to work only with arguments which are provided to your functions by the calling C thread - and not store any references to them afterwards. There's no way to guarantee any variables will not be modified - in general case.

You need to rethink your architecture so that such need does not arise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to make sure that the code which sets the variables values is synchronized, puting a lock while reading is pointless and won't work. It's not only the atomicity of the operations, it's also data visibility - updates to those variables may not be visible to other threads.

If you control the main thread you have to create a new variable for each of those you have to access, access it from the main thread, and using locks, set the value of the newly created variable. Then, from other threads, access only those synchronized variables.

```
int myVal = 0;

int main() {
  while(!shouldQuit()) {
    doSomeIndependentStuff();
    pthread_lock(&mutex);
    myVal = independentGlobalVal;
    pthread_unlock(&mutex);
  }
}

int getMyVal() {
  int retVal = 0;
  pthread_lock(&mutex);
  retVal  = myVal;
  pthread_unlock(&mutex);
  return retval;
}
```